# Implement complicated group by on list if dicts without pandas

Tags: python

I have the next data:

```
data = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 1, 'count2': 4, 'count3': 6},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 6, 'count2': 7, 'count3': 2},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 3, 'count2': 9, 'count3': 10},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 0, 'count2': 3, 'count3': 4},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 2, 'count2': 8, 'count3': 5},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 7, 'count2': 1, 'count3': 0},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 0, 'count3': 3},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 5, 'count3': 7}]
```

How to group by this list of dicts on keys `id`, `name`, `city` and sum keys `count1`, `count2`, `count3`, without using pandas? I want to get the next result:

```
[{'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 16, 'count2': 14, 'count3': 19},
 {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 8, 'count2': 15, 'count3': 7},
 {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 8, 'count3': 11}]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution using `itertools.groupby` and `collections.Counter`:

```
data = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 1, 'count2': 4, 'count3': 6},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 6, 'count2': 7, 'count3': 2},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 3, 'count2': 9, 'count3': 10},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 0, 'count2': 3, 'count3': 4},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 2, 'count2': 8, 'count3': 5},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 7, 'count2': 1, 'count3': 0},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 0, 'count3': 3},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 5, 'count3': 7}]

from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

counters = {}
for v, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda k: (k['id'], k['name'], k['city'])), lambda k: (k['id'], k['name'], k['city'])):
    for item in g:
        counters.setdefault(v, Counter()).update({'count1': item['count1'], 'count2': item['count2'], 'count3': item['count3']})

out = [{'id':_id, 'name': name, 'city': city,
        'count1': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count1'],
        'count2': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count2'],
        'count3': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count3']}  for (_id, name, city) in counters]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=120)
```

Prints:

```
[{'city': 'London', 'count1': 16, 'count2': 14, 'count3': 19, 'id': 123, 'name': 'John'},
 {'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 8, 'count2': 15, 'count3': 7, 'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam'},
 {'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 8, 'count3': 11, 'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick'}]
```

---

OR without groupby (This will be O(n)):

```
from collections import Counter

counters = {}
for item in data:
    v = (item['id'], item['name'], item['city'])
    counters.setdefault(v, Counter()).update({'count1': item['count1'], 'count2': item['count2'], 'count3': item['count3']})

out = [{'id':_id, 'name': name, 'city': city,
        'count1': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count1'],
        'count2': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count2'],
        'count3': counters[(_id, name, city)]['count3']}  for (_id, name, city) in counters]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=120)
```

Comment: For funsies (works on Python 3.7): `out = [{**dict(zip(['id', 'name', 'city'], k)), **counters[k]} for k in counters]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working solution in python without any module: (Optimization is still required)

```
data = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 1, 'count2': 4, 'count3': 6},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 6, 'count2': 7, 'count3': 2},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 3, 'count2': 9, 'count3': 10},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 0, 'count2': 3, 'count3': 4},
        {'id': 456, 'name': 'Sam', 'city': 'Paris', 'count1': 2, 'count2': 8, 'count3': 5},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 7, 'count2': 1, 'count3': 0},
        {'id': 123, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'London', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 0, 'count3': 3},
        {'id': 789, 'name': 'Nick', 'city': 'Berlin', 'count1': 5, 'count2': 5, 'count3': 7}]
unique_ids = set([item['id'] for item in data])
group_by_items = []
for id in unique_ids:
    new_item = {'id': id, 'name': '', 'city': '', 'count1': 0, 'count2': 0, 'count3': 0}
    for item in data:
        new_item['city'] = item['city']
        new_item['name'] = item['name']
        if item['id'] == id:
            new_item['count1'] += item['count1']
            new_item['count2'] += item['count2']
            new_item['count3'] += item['count3']
    group_by_items.append(new_item)
print(group_by_items)
```